# How to insert an array of String into Selectpicker in HTML

Tags: java, html, arrays, jsp, bootstrap-selectpicker

Im trying to introduce the Array of Strings shown below into a Selectpicker so the options of the selectpicker would be the elements of the array.

```
<script>
        String str[] = (String[]) request.getAttribute("intervenciones"); 
        for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            option += '<option value="'+ str[i] + '">' + str[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#procedimiento').append(option);
</script>
```

```
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="procedimiento">Procedimiento</label>                                
    <select name="procedimiento" id="procedimiento" class="form-control selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-size="3" style="width: 100px;">
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your question more that what you exactly want?

Comment: I think the solution is something similar to the code I wrote, but I can't see in the selectpicker tab the elements of the array, it simply appears empty

Comment: you are mixing `jsp` and `js` they both are not same,, simply use `jstl` to print your result inside option

Comment: i never used  <c:out>, what should i put inside option?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont know what `data-show-subtex` and so is but I think it is for some jquery plugin.

If that is the code you are running, it wont work because in Javascript you dont declare variables like that.

You should change your code to this:

```js
// change this for request.getAttribute(...)
var options = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];
var option = '';
for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
    option += '<option value="'+ options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>';
  }
$('#procedimiento').append(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="procedimiento">Procedimiento</label>                                
    <select name="procedimiento" id="procedimiento" class="form-control selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-size="3" style="width: 100px;">
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstl `forEach` loop to print values inside your select-box .i.e :

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <select name="procedimiento" id="procedimiento" class="form-control selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-size="3" style="width: 100px;">
    <c:forEach var="inter" items="${intervenciones}" > //<-pass your value here which set in requst attribute
             <option value="${inter}">${inter}</option>//<-printing options
     </c:forEach>
 </select>
```